# Can we Merge two files using Hadoop MapReduce Code

Tags: join, hadoop, mapreduce

Are we  able to merge two files using MapReduce code .

I am aware of `-getmerge and cat command`.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
try {
    FileSystem hdfs = FileSystem.get(conf);
    FileUtil.copyMerge(hdfs, new Path(srcPath), hdfs, new Path(
                            dstPath), false, conf, null);
} catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```

srcPath - dir of individualfiles.